# What version soap does Salesforce use?

Tags: soap, callout

I'm having the worst time ever trying to find out what SOAP Salesforce uses.  I haven't used it in forever the developer from our other system is asking me if it uses SOAP 1.1 or 1.2.

NOTE-I will be making a call out with a SOAP call.

Comment: did you see this? https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BroSAAS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Salesforce uses SOAP 1.1. If you look at the WSDL that you can generate from within the setup>develop>API and choose one of the WSDL's you will see

```
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
```

If it were SOAP 1.2 it would say:

```
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"
```